# Blazor with FontAwesome

Tags: javascript, css, blazor, font-awesome

I am using Blazor and using a font awesome.
I noticed very slow loading of a table when font-awesome javascript lib is added.

When I use this setup all works well, but loading is slow

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/font-awesome/css/all.min.css" />
<script src="lib/font-awesome/js/all.min.js"></script>
```

When I remove the JS and keep just the CSS, icons are corrupted but loading is fast

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/font-awesome/css/all.min.css" />
```

When I use direct link to font-awesome, all works well and loading is fast

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v6.2.1/css/all.css" />
```

I have compared the content of https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v6.2.1/css/all.css with my local lib/font-awesome/css/all.min.css and they seem to be identical.

Any idea what is going on here? Why JS is not needed when the css is loaded from remote repository and why would the performance be so different?

Comment: Check if you are missing the `webfonts` folder which is required for using fontawesome with css only. It should be inside your `lib/font-awesome/` folder. [Documentation](https://fontawesome.com/docs/web/setup/host-yourself/webfonts#add-font-awesome-files-to-your-project).

Comment: Yes, I did not have webfonts installed.. after installing them and removing JS, it works smoothly :) Thank you

Comment: You guys should put this in an answer so @Thorberg can select your answer and close the  thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if you are missing the `/webfonts` folder which is required for using fontawesome with css only. It should be inside your `lib/font-awesome/` folder. [Documentation](https://fontawesome.com/docs/web/setup/host-yourself/webfonts#add-font-awesome-files-to-your-project).